# How are two rows inserted?

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run the following code, it inserts two rows that are like `'07_%'`, that do not exist initially in `tlp` because date created is `'07-AUG-15'`.

Initially in `GLOB` I have 600 rows which are `like '07_%'`, so how are these rows inserted??

```
  INSERT INTO TLP
            (LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, EMAIL1, USERID) 
SELECT NAME, GIVEN_NAME, MAIL, LOGIN
FROM   gLOB 
WHERE (( ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT EMAIL1 
                     FROM   TLP 
                     WHERE  GLOB.mail = TLP.email1 ) 
         AND GLOB.mail IS NOT NULL )
         AND GLOB.COUNTRY='GERMANY' )
        OR (( NOT EXISTS (SELECT userid
                         FROM   TLP
                         WHERE  GLOB.LOGIN = TLP.userid ) 
              )
  AND GLOB.COUNTRY='Germany'))
  and ( exists (select FIRSTNAME
                  from TLP
                  where (gLOB.name not like '07_%' AND 
                 GLOB.name not like 'TR_%' AND
                 GLOB.name not like 'ST_%' AND

                    GLOB.name is not null))

                 ));
```

Comment: I've had a go and trying to clarify what you're asking, but I'm not sure I understand it enough so might not have got it right. WHy have you mentioned 07-Aug-15? Are you expecting no rows with 07_% to be inserted, or one, or more than two - can you explain why what you are seeing is wrong? It looks like you may have your logic wrong from parentheses in the wrong place - the final `AND` isn't correlated to anything else - but without some sample data and expected/actual output it'd hard to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to filter out values such `07-AUG-15` but your like pattern says `07_%`. It should be

```
gal.name not like '07-%'
```

Also, your last part as pointed below makes no sense; rather you should include those condition in main query `WHERE` clause.

```
and ( exists (select FIRSTNAME
                  from TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY
                  where (gal.name not like '07_%' AND 
                 gal.name not like 'TR_%' AND
                 gal.name not like 'ST_%' AND
                  gal.name not like 'KB_%'  AND
                   gal.name not like 'HS_%'  AND
                    gal.name is not null))
```

Your `SELECT` should look like

```
SELECT SUBSTR(NAME, 1, 50),SUBSTR( GIVEN_NAME, 1, 50), DEPARTMENT, PHONE, SUBSTR(MAIL, 1, 100), SUBSTR(LOGIN, 1, 255), SYSDATE 
FROM   gal 
WHERE ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT EMAIL1 
                     FROM   TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY 
                     WHERE  GAL.mail = TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY.email1)

        OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT userid
                         FROM   TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY 
                         WHERE  gAL.LOGIN = TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY.userid))
AND GAL.mail IS NOT NULL AND GAL.COUNTRY='GERMANY'
AND (            gal.name not like '07_%' OR 
                 gal.name not like 'TR_%' OR
                 gal.name not like 'ST_%' OR
                  gal.name not like 'KB_%'  OR
                   gal.name not like 'HS_%'  OR
                    gal.name is not null);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but my model is like '07_%'. Like '07-%' it's another thing

Comment: First time I try whit OR but doesn't work. For me whit OR was more logic, but apparent just whit AND works. :(

Comment: but I don't understand way from 600 rows, two are inserted, that was my question .... and this is not the answer