# how I can insert just one row?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How I can make this code to insert just first person, not all, how have the specified condition ??
And another question: I can make this code more optimum? and how ?

```
INSERT INTO TLP
            (LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME,  EMAIL1, USERID  ) 
SELECT NAME,  GIVEN_NAME, MAIL, LOGIN, SYSDATE

FROM   GLOB 
WHERE (( ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT EMAIL1 
                     FROM   TLP
                     WHERE  GLOB.mail = TLP.email1 ) 
         AND GLOB.mail IS NOT NULL )
         AND GLOB.COUNTRY='France' )
        OR (( NOT EXISTS (SELECT userid
                         FROM   TLP 
                         WHERE  GLOB.LOGIN = TLP.userid ) 

  AND GLOB.COUNTRY='Germany'))
  and ( exists (select FIRSTNAME
                  from TLP
                  where (gLOB.name not like '07_%' AND 
                 glob.name not like 'TR_%' AND
                 glob.name not like 'ST_%' AND                     
                    glob.name is not null))

                 ));
```

Comment: Add FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY at the end. (BTW, which row do you want...)

Comment: How does this relate to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31912785/266304)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add one more condition at the end.

```
and rownum=1;
```

This will do.

There are lot of factors you need to consider for optimizing. This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/select-optimization.html) might help.

Answer (score 1):

you can rownum = 1 in where condition.

Some examples are given below:
In first example, we can order by data and get only one record by using rownum <= 1. It will give only one record.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT *
     FROM audit_table ORDER BY activity_id DESC)
WHERE  rownum <= 1;
```

Other simple example:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM audit_table
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (
  SELECT deptno, ename
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY deptno) rno
  FROM emp
 ORDER BY deptno
 )
WHERE rno <= 1
```

In above example we use ROW_NUMBER() to oder by one of the coulmn and take only one record by using alias and put condition in where clause.